# Error installing Oozie 4.2.0

Tags: apache, maven, hadoop, oozie

While trying to execute `mkdistro.sh` getting the following error:

> [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
>   [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for `org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:4.2.0`: Could not transfer artifact `org.apache:apache:pom:16` from/to central (`http://repo1.maven.org/maven2`): `repo1.maven.org`: unknown error and '`parent.relativePath`' points at wrong local POM @ line 22, column 13
>    @
>   [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR]   The project `org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:4.2.0` (`/usr/local/Oozie_4.2.0_O/oozie-4.2.0/pom.xml`) has 1 error
>   [ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for `org.apache.oozie:oozie-main:4.2.0`: Could not transfer artifact `org.apache:apache:pom:16` from/to central (`http://repo1.maven.org/maven2`): `repo1.maven.org`: unknown error and '`parent.relativePath`' points at wrong local POM @ line 22, column 13: Unknown host `repo1.maven.org`: unknown error -> [Help 2]
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the `-e` switch.
>   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the `-X` switch to enable full debug logging.
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

System information:

- Hadoop Version: 2.4.0
- Maven Version: 3.3.9
- Oozie: 4.2.0

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Are you behind the proxy?

Comment: i think the issue is with the maven proxy setting